# I am training a Genomic-ULMFIT model but I am not able to run some functions

Tags: python, oop, fast-ai

Hi there I am tring to use a Model for genomics using this code:
https://github.com/kheyer/Genomic-ULMFiT

It uses as some classes from fastai like this:

```
from fastai import *
from fastai.text.all import *

class GenomicTextClasDataBunch(TextClasDataBunch):
    @classmethod
    def from_df(cls, path:PathOrStr, train_df:DataFrame, valid_df:DataFrame, test_df:Optional[DataFrame]=None,
                tokenizer:Tokenizer=None, vocab:Vocab=None, classes:Collection[str]=None, text_cols:IntsOrStrs=1,
                label_cols:IntsOrStrs=0, label_delim:str=None, chunksize:int=10000, max_vocab:int=60000,
                min_freq:int=2, mark_fields:bool=False, pad_idx=0, pad_first=True, bs=64, **kwargs) -> DataBunch:
        "Create a `TextDataBunch` from DataFrames. `kwargs` are passed to the dataloader creation."
        processor = _get_genomic_processor(tokenizer=tokenizer, vocab=vocab, chunksize=chunksize, max_vocab=max_vocab,
                                   min_freq=min_freq, mark_fields=mark_fields)
        if classes is None and is_listy(label_cols) and len(label_cols) > 1: classes = label_cols
        src = ItemLists(path, TextList.from_df(train_df, path, cols=text_cols, processor=processor),
                        TextList.from_df(valid_df, path, cols=text_cols, processor=processor))
        src = src.label_from_df(cols=label_cols, classes=classes, label_delim=label_delim)
        if test_df is not None: src.add_test(TextList.from_df(test_df, path, cols=text_cols))
        d1 = src.databunch(**kwargs)
        
        datasets = cls._init_ds(d1.train_ds, d1.valid_ds, d1.test_ds)
        collate_fn = partial(pad_collate, pad_idx=pad_idx, pad_first=pad_first, backwards=False)
        train_sampler = SortishSampler(datasets[0].x, key=lambda t: len(datasets[0][t][0].data), bs=bs//2)
        train_dl = DataLoader(datasets[0], batch_size=bs, sampler=train_sampler, drop_last=True, **kwargs)
        dataloaders = [train_dl]
        for ds in datasets[1:]:
            lengths = [len(t) for t in ds.x.items]
            sampler = SortSampler(ds.x, key=lengths.__getitem__)
            dataloaders.append(DataLoader(ds, batch_size=bs, sampler=sampler, **kwargs))
            
        return cls(*dataloaders, path=path, collate_fn=collate_fn)
```

However I got some erros like that:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-e2adc6490f4e> in <module>
----> 1 class GenomicTextClasDataBunch(TextClasDataBunch):
      2     @classmethod
      3     def from_df(cls, path:PathOrStr, train_df:DataFrame, valid_df:DataFrame, test_df:Optional[DataFrame]=None,
      4                 tokenizer:Tokenizer=None, vocab:Vocab=None, classes:Collection[str]=None, text_cols:IntsOrStrs=1,
      5                 label_cols:IntsOrStrs=0, label_delim:str=None, chunksize:int=10000, max_vocab:int=60000,

NameError: name 'TextClasDataBunch' is not defined
```

I at first change the "from fasta.text import *" to "from fastai.text.all import *", but still get the error message!
In other parts of the code I receive the same kind of error and in some cases error in arguments to "****init****" functions.

I don't know if I am importing the fastai wrong or the code it not working because differents versions!

I know that 'GenomicTextClasDataBunch' it is a subclass from fastai 'TextClasDataBunch', but I think I need some kind of import to bring the superclass to the code!

Any help would be very appreciated!

Thank you for your time!
Be safe!
Paulo

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes indeed from a version issue. You must have installed fastai with `pip install fastai` but this command installes the version 2 of fastai (https://github.com/fastai/fastai/tree/master/fastai).

The one you need to use `TextClasDataBunch` is the version 1 of fastai. You can install it by running the following command: `pip install fastai==1.0.61`.

By the way, two small side notes on your code:

- Try using a [Python Formatter](https://codebeautify.org/python-formatter-beautifier), as your block of code is pretty hard to read and understand, it would be nice for reader!
- It is not advised to do a `from any_lib import *` as you import in your memory many things that you will not use. Prefer `import any_lib as lib` and then `lib.any_function()`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, but that it is not my code. And I also think it is hard  to read! But i will try out your solution. And the import with fastai the autor says that you could do that because they work hard to avoid name colisions, but... Thank you!